# Exception EZSQLExeption in module VDB1.exe at 002A7A5C. SQL Error: Host'Gareth-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, windows, delphi, networking

I am using Delphi xe2 and I would like to know qhat this error is and by what means I need to get around this, I am attempting to connect my database application to a wamp server through a LAN connection and I seem to have the Hostname username password and port correct but when I attempt to log into the MySQL database I get this error:

> *(Exception EZSQLExeption in module VDB1.exe at 002A7A5C. SQL Error:
>   Host'My-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server)*

Could you please give me a way to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message states:

> Host 'My-PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

And this would indicate that the SQL server is blocking your client based on its host name, 'My-PC'. So, you need to configure your MySQL server to allow connections from that host.